# Is it a problem that a pipe in basement slopes upwards slightly for 9 feet?

Tags: plumbing, sewer

A plumber I hired to rough in new plumbing installed the 3 inch pipe in the basement.

The pipe slopes downward nicely at the required pitch as it leaves the house.

There is a small section (a 9 foot run) where the pipe actually slopes up very slightly as seen on a bubble level.

Is this sure to fail?

The plumber said everything will be fine.

Is there a chance everything is fine?

Thanks!

Comment: If that pipe will carry anything other than clean water then it will block sooner or later ...

Comment: Make him fix it.

Comment: Everything except code compliance and function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason any sewer pipe should slope upward. Gravity is what it is.